# Angular Material: Weird suffix fucntionality

Tags: angular-material

So I stumbled upon a weird one...
I am using angular material's form field component to create my forms...
I noticed that if I use a button inside the mat input field as matSuffix, if I try to submit the form from another field (pressing enter for example)... that field get's the focus and the button (suffix) gets clicked...

Even wrapping the angular material's example and wrapping it in a form I get the same:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frc7tj?file=app/form-field-prefix-suffix-example.html

```
<div class="example-container">
  <form>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Enter your password"
        [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
      />
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        matSuffix
        (click)="hide = !hide"
        [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
        [attr.aria-pressed]="hide"
      >
        <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Amount"
        type="number"
        class="example-right-align"
      />
      <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
      <span matSuffix>.00</span>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</div>
```

Just type something into the first (password field) and then click into "amount" field and press enter, observe what happens

the first one gets the focus and the button suffix is clicked....

how can I prevent this behaviour and actually enforce the normal, expected one (form submission on enter key)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `type="button"` to buttons inside the form. By default,  `type="submit"` is using and you are trying to submit the form by pressing `Enter` key. See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frc7tj-e2snms?file=app/form-field-prefix-suffix-example.html).

Comment: yeah, adding type="button" solves it! thanks!